# tkinter Scrollable Frame inside a Label Frame does not getting resized

Tags: python, tkinter

Created 3 Label Frames using python tkinter. First and the second Label Frames widgets getting resized correctly when resizing the window. Third Label Frame contains a  Scrollable Frame which does not resizing. I have gone through many of the stack overflow answers about scrollable frames, but could not solve the issue myself. Scrollbar working correctly. I am new to Python and first time asking question in Stack Overflow. Please excuse if I posted question incorrectly.
Thanks in advance

Here is the images

[Large window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXmPT.png)
[Reduced window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbAaW.png)

Here is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import os
from kiteconnect import KiteConnect
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
import threading

cwd = os.chdir("C:/Users/Admin/myPython/KiteConnect/1_account_authorization")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Quick Order")
root.geometry("1300x400")

#--------------------------Begin---Makes all the windows dynamically resizable and responsive-------------------------------
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) #One column in root
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=0) #Controls row
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=0) #Titles row
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=0) #Quotes row
root.rowconfigure(3, weight=0) #Orders row to be created
root.rowconfigure(4, weight=0) #Positions row to be created
root.rowconfigure(5, weight=0) #GTT Orders row to be created
#--------------------------End---Makes all the windows dynamically resizable and responsive---------------------------------

#--------------------------------------Begin---Zerodha KiteConnect established access---------------------------------------
access_token = open("access_token.txt",'r').read()
key_secret = open("api_key.txt",'r').read().split()
kite = KiteConnect(api_key=key_secret[0])
kite.set_access_token(access_token)
#----------------------------------------End---Zerodha KiteConnect established access---------------------------------------

#---------------------------Begin---Thread---Refresh button loads live market quaotes and display---------------------------
stopQuotes=False
def startQuotesThread():
    t1=threading.Thread(target=startQuotesScan)
    t1.start()
def stopQuotesScan():
    global stopQuotes
    stopQuotes=True
def startQuotesScan():
    refreshTable() #calling clearquotes_Widgets() which destroys all the quotes_Widgets in the quotes terminal
    quotes_Widgets=quotes_Scrollable_Frame.winfo_children()
    i=0
    instruments=[]
    size=len(quotes_Widgets)/17
    while(i<size):
        if((quotes_Widgets[i*17]["text"].startswith("NIFTY")) or (quotes_Widgets[i*17]["text"].startswith("BANKNIFTY"))):
            instruments.append("NFO:"+quotes_Widgets[i*17]["text"])
        i+=1
    change=0
    while(True):
        quote=kite.quote(instruments)
        i=0
        global stopQuotes
        if(stopQuotes==True):
            stopQuotes=False
            break
        while(i<size):
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+1]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]['depth']['buy'][0]['quantity']
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+2]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]['depth']['buy'][0]['price']
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+4]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]['depth']['sell'][0]['price']
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+5]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]['depth']['sell'][0]['quantity']
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+6]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]["last_price"]
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+7]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]["ohlc"]["open"]
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+8]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]["ohlc"]["high"]
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+9]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]["ohlc"]["low"]
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+10]["text"]=quote[instruments[i]]["ohlc"]["close"]
            change=((quote[instruments[i]]["last_price"]-quote[instruments[i]]["ohlc"]["close"])/ quote[instruments[i]]["ohlc"]["close"])*100
            quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+11]["text"]="{:.2f}".format(change)
            if(change>0):
                quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+11].config(foreground="green")
            else:
                quotes_Widgets[(i*17)+11].config(foreground="red")
            i+=1
#----------------------------------End---Thread---Refresh button loads live market quaotes and display----------------------

#----------------------------------------Begin---Stop all threads on window close------------------------------------------
def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        stopQuotesScan()
        root.destroy()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
#----------------------------------------End---Stop all threads on window close--------------------------------------------

#----------------------------------------------------Begin : Controls frame-------------------------------------------------
controls_Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Controls")
controls_Frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news", padx=10, pady=5)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
controls_Frame.columnconfigure(11, weight=1)

connect_button =  Button(controls_Frame, text="CONNECT") 
connect_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
username_label = Label(controls_Frame)
username_label.grid(row=0,column=1)
search_label = Label(controls_Frame, text="SEARCH & ADD")
search_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
search_combobox = ttk.Combobox(controls_Frame)
search_combobox.grid(row=0,column=3)
refresh_button = Button(controls_Frame, text="Refresh", command=startQuotesThread)
refresh_button.grid(row=0, column=4)
stopquotes_button = Button(controls_Frame, text="STOP", command=stopQuotesScan)
stopquotes_button.grid(row=0, column=5)
blank_label = Label(controls_Frame)
blank_label.grid(row=0,column=6)
blank_label = Label(controls_Frame)
blank_label.grid(row=0,column=7)
blank_label = Label(controls_Frame)
blank_label.grid(row=0,column=8)
trailstoploss_label = Label(controls_Frame, text="TRAIL STOP LOSS")
trailstoploss_label.grid(row=0, column=9)
starttrail_button = Button(controls_Frame, text="START")
starttrail_button.grid(row=0, column=10)
stoptrail_button = Button(controls_Frame, text="STOP")
stoptrail_button.grid(row=0, column=11)
for controls_Frame_widget in controls_Frame.winfo_children():
    controls_Frame_widget.grid_configure(padx=2, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
#----------------------------------------------------End : Controls frame---------------------------------------------------

#----------------------------------------------------Begin : Titles frame---------------------------------------------------
title_Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Titles")
title_Frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news", padx=10, pady=0)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(11, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(12, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(13, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(14, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(15, weight=1)
title_Frame.columnconfigure(16, weight=1)
instrument_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Instrument", width=22).grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=3)
buyquantity_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Buy Qty", width=8).grid(row=0, column=1)
sell_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Sell", width=14).grid(row=0, column=2)
qty_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Qty", width=4).grid(row=0, column=3, ipadx=3)
buy_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Buy", width=13).grid(row=0, column=4, ipadx=3)
sellquantity_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Sell Qty", width=7).grid(row=0, column=5)
ltp_label = Label(title_Frame, text="LTP", width=6).grid(row=0, column=6, ipadx=1)
open_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Open", width=6).grid(row=0, column=7, ipadx=1)
high_label = Label(title_Frame, text="High", width=6).grid(row=0, column=8, ipadx=1)
low_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Low", width=6).grid(row=0, column=9, ipadx=1)
close_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Close", width=6).grid(row=0, column=10, ipadx=1)
chg_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Chg%", width=6).grid(row=0, column=11, ipadx=2)
product_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Product", width=9).grid(row=0, column=12)
type_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Type", width=9).grid(row=0, column=13)
sl_label = Label(title_Frame, text="SL%", width=5).grid(row=0, column=14, ipadx=2)
tsl_label = Label(title_Frame, text="TSL%", width=5).grid(row=0, column=15, ipadx=2)
del_label = Label(title_Frame, text="Del", width=3).grid(row=0, column=16, ipadx=10)
for title_Frame_widget in title_Frame.winfo_children():
    title_Frame_widget.grid_configure(padx=2, pady=1, sticky="ew")
    title_Frame_widget.configure(fg="white", bg="blue")
#------------------------------------------------------End : Titles frame---------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------Begin : Quotes frame--------------------------------------------------
quotesFrame = LabelFrame(root, width=850, text="Quotes")
quotesFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news", padx=10, pady=5)

"""
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(11, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(12, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(13, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(14, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(15, weight=1)
quotesFrame.columnconfigure(16, weight=1)
"""

quotes_Canvas = Canvas(quotesFrame, bd = 10, bg = 'light grey', highlightthickness  = 2, highlightbackground = 'light blue')
quotes_Scrollbar = Scrollbar(quotesFrame, orient="vertical", command=quotes_Canvas.yview)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame = Frame(quotes_Canvas)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: quotes_Canvas.configure(scrollregion=quotes_Canvas.bbox("all")))
quotes_Canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=quotes_Scrollable_Frame, anchor="center")
quotes_Canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=quotes_Scrollbar.set)

def refreshTable(): 
    i = 0
    clearquotes_Widgets() #Destroy all the quotes_Widgets in the frame
    f=open("symbols_selected.txt") #file open receives string argument        
    stockList=f.read()
    stocks=stockList.split("\n")
    for value in stocks:
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text=value, width=27, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=0)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=10, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=1)
        ttk.Button(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=16, command=lambda row=i, :sell_nfo(row)).grid(row=i, column=2)
        if(value.startswith("NIFTY")):
            combobox_quantity=ttk.Combobox(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, values=["50", "100", "150", "200", "250", "300", "350", "400"], width=3)
            combobox_quantity.current(0)
        else:
            combobox_quantity=ttk.Combobox(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, values=["15", "30", "45", "60", "75", "90", "105", "120"], width=3)
            combobox_quantity.current(1)
        combobox_quantity.grid(row=i, column=3)
        ttk.Button(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=16, command=lambda row=i, : buy_nfo(row)).grid(row=i, column=4)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=10, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=5)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=8, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=6)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=8, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=7)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=8, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=8)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=8, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=9)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=8, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=10)
        ttk.Label(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="", width=8, relief="groove").grid(row=i, column=11)
        combobox_product = ttk.Combobox(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, values=["NRML", "MIS"], width=8)
        combobox_product.current(0)
        combobox_product.grid(row=i, column=12)
        combobox_order_type=ttk.Combobox(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, values=["GTT", "COVER", "MARKET"], width=8)
        combobox_order_type.current(0)
        combobox_order_type.grid(row=i, column=13)
        combobox_stoploss=ttk.Combobox(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, values=["5", "10", "15"], width=4)
        combobox_stoploss.current(0)
        combobox_stoploss.grid(row=i, column=14)
        combobox_trailstop=ttk.Combobox(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, values=["5", "10", "15"], width=4)
        combobox_trailstop.current(0)
        combobox_trailstop.grid(row=i, column=15)
        button_delete=ttk.Button(quotes_Scrollable_Frame, text="x", width=4)
        button_delete.grid(row=i, column=16)
        for quotes_Scrollable_Frame_widget in quotes_Scrollable_Frame.winfo_children():
            quotes_Scrollable_Frame_widget.grid_configure(padx=2, pady=1, sticky="ew")
        i+=1

quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(11, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(12, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(13, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(14, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(15, weight=1)
quotes_Scrollable_Frame.columnconfigure(16, weight=1)

quotes_Canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
quotes_Scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
#-----------------------------------------------------End : Quotes frame--------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------Begin : Clear quotes_Widgets from the Quotes Frame----------------------------------
def clearquotes_Widgets(): 
    quotes_Widgets = quotes_Scrollable_Frame.winfo_children()
    i=0
    while(i<len(quotes_Widgets)):
        quotes_Widgets[i].destroy()
        i+=1
#---------------------------------------End : Clear quotes_Widgets from the Quotes Frame----------------------------------
root.mainloop()
```

A main window with all the widgets getting resized.

Comment: I'd say you didn't write the question wrong but this is just way too much code, next time just keep this in mind: [mre]

Comment: Sure, I will be careful next time. By mistake posted the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the width of `quotes_Scrollable_Frame` whenever `quotes_Canvas` is resized:

- bind `"<Configure>"` event on `quotes_Canvas`
- resize the width of `quotes_Scrollable_Frame` to the same of `quotes_Canvas` inside the binding callback

```py
...
# set bd=0 and highlightthickness=0
quotes_Canvas = Canvas(quotesFrame, bg='light grey', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
...
# added tag="frame" option
quotes_Canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=quotes_Scrollable_Frame, anchor="center", tag="frame")
# set width of quotes_Scrollable_Frame whenever canvas is resized
quotes_Canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: e.widget.itemconfig("frame", width=e.width))
...
```

Comment: Thank yo very much. Its working fantastic. Thanks a lot for your valuable piece of code that saved me from struggling to find a solution. Best regards,